# Move-Item moves entire source directory instead of specified files

Tags: powershell

In PowerShell, I'm trying to use Move-Item to move all files containing the string "2017", located in `$Source`, to `$MovieDst`

The files that I want to move in `$Source` are individual `.mkv` files with the string "2017" in the filename, located at the root of `$Source` - they are not in a directory.

If I hash out `Move-Item` and un-hash `Write-Host $NoDirMovie`, it outputs the following:

```
ExampleFile.2017.mkv
ExampleFile2.2017.mkv
```

So, it definitely knows which are the correct files to be referencing. But as soon as I use `Move-Item`, it moves the entire `$source directory` into `$MovieDst`. I can't use `-Exclude *COMPLETED_DOWNLOADS*` as it includes the very files that I want to move.

So, I'm a bit stuck - It can't move my files, because it FIRST wants to move the entire directory containing them. Is there a way to stop it from moving the entire `$Source` directory, and JUST move only the contents of `$Source` that contain the string "2017" ?

```
$Source = "C:\TV Shows 7\COMPLETED_DOWNLOADS"
$MovieDst = "C:\TV Shows 7\COMPLETED DOWNLOADS_Sorted\MOVIES"
$NoDirMovies = dir $Source *2017*

foreach($NoDirMovie in $NoDirMovies | where {$_ -ne $Source})
{
Move-Item -Path $Source -Destination $MovieDst
#Write-Host $NoDirMovie
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you storing the files you want in `$NoDirMovie`, then passing `$Source` to `Move-item`?

Surely you want:

```
foreach($NoDirMovie in $NoDirMovies | where {$_ -ne $Source})
{
    Move-Item -Path $NoDirMovie -Destination $MovieDst
    #Write-Host $NoDirMovie
}
```

**Edit**

That's a simple fix, which I haven't tried. A few things:

- `dir` is an alias for the built-in PowerShell Cmdlet [`Get-ChildItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem)
- Your loop `Where` is illogical. `$NoDirMovies` are files in directory `$Source`, so they will never equal `$Source` (assume this was an attempt to not copy directory?)
- Worth checking if the directory you are trying to copy to exists.

**V2 (I tried this one)**

```
$Source   = "C:\TV Shows 7\COMPLETED_DOWNLOADS"
$MovieDst = "C:\TV Shows 7\COMPLETED DOWNLOADS_Sorted\MOVIES"
$filter   = "2017"

If(!(Test-Path $MovieDst)){
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $MovieDst    
}

foreach($file in (Get-ChildItem $Source | Where-object {$_.Name -match $filter})){
    Move-Item -Path $file.FullName -Destination $MovieDst
}
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO your approach is overcomplicated. Move-Item accepts piped input, so

```
$Source = "C:\TV Shows 7\COMPLETED_DOWNLOADS"
$MovieDst = "C:\TV Shows 7\COMPLETED DOWNLOADS_Sorted\MOVIES\"
Get-ChildItem -Path $Source -Filter "*2017*.mkv" |Where {!($_.PSIsContainer)}
  Move-Item -Destination $MovieDst -WhatIf
```

If the outpout looks OK, remove the `-WhatIf`